# Accents in glossary terms

Tags: accents, glossary

There are a number of postings here that address *part* of my problem, but none seem to solve *all* my problem.

I'm using tufte-book and want to include glossary entries that include accents.  To the best of my understanding, the central problem is that the arguments within `\newglossaryentry{}` cannot include accents.  However, `name{}` can.  Thus the best (yet incomplete) solution I've found is illustrated here:

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

 \newglossaryentry{catalog raisonne}{
     name={catalog raisonn{\'e}},
     description={my definition here}
    }

\begin{document}

We can read a \gls{catalog raisonne}...

\end{document}
```

and the page numbering is correct and the printed entry in the glossary contains the accent.  HOWEVER of course the entry within the body of the text does *not* have the accent (when it must).

I've tried all manner of using é, or `\gls{catalog raisonne@{catalog raisonn{\'e}}}` and such, but invariably have errors.

I'd really like to avoid solutions recoding using UNICODE specifications as I might need to review my entire large book for teeny errors that likely would arise.

What is the simplest, least-intrusive, solution to getting accents in glossary terms, both in the text body and in the printed glossary itself?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @DG'. Sure...  I'll have it up in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `\makeglossary` instead of `\makenoidxglossaries` it works fine (run with [arara](https://ctan.org/pkg/arara)):

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: makeglossaries 
% arara: makeindex 
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on } 
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }

\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{glossaries}

% \makenoidxglossaries
\makeglossary
\makeindex

\newglossaryentry{catalog raisonne}{
  name={catalog raisonn{\'e}},
  description={my definition here}
}

\begin{document}

We can read\index{read} a \gls{catalog raisonne}...

\backmatter

\printglossaries
\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much (accept).  I found that after running with \makeglossary I could revert to \makenoidxglossary and the layout and so on worked fine.  While I don't understand it fully, that's fine... good enough for publication.